# How to check for existence of a pointer before delete in qt

Tags: c++, qt, delete-operator

I am using a `QAbstractTableModel`. The model holds data in it. It is created and deleted upon user clicks.

This is the connected slot after user click to create a model:

```
void clicked(){
    model = new QAbstractTableModel(data);
    model->setManyThings();
}
```

This is the connected slot after user click to clear the model:

```
void clear(){
    if (model != nullptr)
        delete model;
}
```

However, this cannot check whether `model` is exist. If I click clear twice the program crash directly. If the model was not created be I click clear, the program crashed directly.

So how to check whether model exist

Comment: Possible `model` after `delete` not set to `nullptr`. You should do it manually `if (model != nullptr) { delete model; model = nullptr; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are deleting the `model` object on the first call, obviously in the second call it crashes because you were trying to call an already deleted object.

In fact, you are actually chekcing if `model` exists, if `model != nullptr` means that this pointer is pointing to an actual object.
If you want to reset the 'model' object just create a new one after deleting the other:

```
void clear(){
    if (model != nullptr)
    {
        delete model;
        model = new QAbstractTableModel(data);
    }
}
```

If you want to just delete it and continue with the proper checking just set the pointer to `nullptr`:

```
void clear(){
    if (model != nullptr)
    {
        delete model;
        model = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am curious about why delete doesn't set the pointer to null by default. There should not be any drawback but it can prevent double deletion of an object.

Comment: @tom c++ actually doesnt have it, is up to you to manage it. you can easily create a function to delete and auto set the pointer to nullptr.

Comment: I know something like '#define my_delete(x) {delete x; x = NULL;}' could do. But I think double deletion should be an error encountered by many programmers. When they run the program, they can notice the problem and fix easily. But I just curious that why it is not set default to prevent this stupid thing. XD

Comment: @tom , notice that you are deleting whatever the pointer is pointing, not the pointer itself, so in fact i can create another object in there and delete it. For the behaviour you want you may check smart pointers http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/ check the `managed pointers` ones

Answer (score 2):

Just set the pointer to null in the constructor and in `clear` after deleting.

Better yet, use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't test whether an arbitrary pointer is valid, but your `clear` should "null" `model` to indicate that it's been deleted:

```
void clear(){
    delete model;
    model = nullptr;
}
```

Note that it's valid to `delete` a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this situation you have to care about the value of the `model` pointer. Here are several steps:

a) Initialized the `model` pointer in your class constructor,

b) Set the `model` pointer value to null after deleting it, i.e:

```
void clear() {
    if (model != 0) {
        delete model;
        model = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't stick to use `0` on nulling pointers, use `nullptr`instead

Comment: @DanielSanchez since this is Qt the ``0`` is the prefered way expected by the framework.

Comment: @DanielSanchez , Really? Are you sure everyone use the same compiler? Instead of down-voting you might point that the `nullptr` is preferable in some cases.

Comment: @SebastianLange, it will mostly depends on the compiler more than the framework, althoug qt is quite big and old and may use `0` internally is still a better practice to use the standard (just my opinion).

Comment: Qt expects a pointer, it doesn’t care about the literal you use. nullptr is the way to go if you can use C++11. Qt itself uses Q_NULLPTR these daysm which uses nullptr or 0, depending on whether C++11 is enabled or not.

Comment: @vahancho: if (foo != 0) delete foo; smells bad - one should omit the if (foo != 0) (delete on nullpointers is safe).

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, I agree, but `if (foo != 0)` check is harmless anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest start using smart pointers. There are many options to check if the pointer exists.

- Since you are using Qt, have a look at [QPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) for `QObject` based classes.

  - This pointer will reset itself to 0 if the object gets deleted, thus you do not need to implement a macro or your own class.
- Use the [std::shared_ptr] if you are using c++11. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) since it will also set itself to `nullptr` if the object gets deleted.

There are many other smart pointers in the [C++11](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541067/Cplusplus-Smart-Pointers) standard as well as a lot in [Qt](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/08/25/count-with-me-how-many-smart-pointer-classes-does-qt-have/) (this is quite an old link, but the information is still valid).